# Gradle eclipse using incorrect version for dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gradle, ear

I'm migrating a project to gradle to resolve dependencies, generate the eclipse project and build the project and I'm with a problem with the version of some dependencies on eclipse project. Here's the build.gradle of the project. It's an EAR with sub-projects.

```
apply plugin: 'ear'

def eclipseJbossName = 'org.eclipse.jst.server.core.container/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core.server.runtime.runtimeTarget/JBoss 6.x Runtime'
def defaultEarConfig = rootDir.getAbsolutePath() + '/ear.gradle'

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    eclipse {
        classpath {
            containers eclipseJbossName
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "mvnrepository"
            url = "http://mvnrepository.com/"
        }
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            name = 'jboss'
            url = 'http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/'
        }
    }
}

subprojects {
    configurations {
        provided
    }
    apply plugin: 'java'
    sourceCompatibility = 1.6
    targetCompatibility = 1.6
    sourceSets {
        main {
            compileClasspath += configurations.provided
            compileClasspath += configurations.compile
            compileClasspath += configurations.runtime
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    deploy (project(path: 'anEJB')) {
        transitive = false
    }
    deploy (project(path: 'anotherEJB')) {
        transitive = false
    }
    deploy (project(path: 'aWAR', configuration: 'archives')) {
        transitive = false
    }
    earlib ('commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.6') {
        transitive = false
    }
    //lots of other dependencies and all with transitive=false
}
//configuration of my subprojects
```

When I call `gradle ear` it builds and generate my artifact correctly. In the lib directory inside the root of the EAR there's all my earlibs with its correct versions. When I call `gradle cleanEclipse eclipse` it generates my project right, but when I see the build path inside eclipse it is using an incorrect version for commons beanutils. It is using the version 1.8. This is not happening for all my dependencies, but there are others with this problem. I've put all to not resolve the transitive dependencies.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot reproduce your problem. Maybe you can write a short reproducer for it? Which version of Gradle do you use?

Comment: For me it works with Gradle 2.1 ... sorry ...

Answer (score -3):

You can click the project in Eclipse with right mouse button, then click properties. And select "Java Build Path" then click "Libraries" tab. Finally remove all jars besides "Gradle Dependencies" & "JRE System Libraries".

Done. Try it.